Open Swift native code in flutter container
Can we open native code written in Swift in a flutter container? I have to open my below native code in the flutter container.
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
            let closeButton = UIButton(type: .system)
                         closeButton.setTitle("Close", for: .normal)
                         closeButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: 80, height: 50)
                         closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goBack), for: .touchUpInside)
                         self.view.addSubview(closeButton)
                 
                 
    
                 activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
                         activityIndicator.center = view.center
                         activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                         view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    
            self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    let url123 = appDelegate.paymentUrl
    let url = URL(string: url123)!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    //setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    //self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
    //self.webView.uiDelegate = self
}

